# Forcing a store into memory (dojo 1.7)

Tags: combobox, dojo, store

I have the following code that works great....

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" url="[% c.uri_for('/') -%]sample_name" jsId="sampleNameStore" class="invisible"></div>

<select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox" id="sample_name" searchAttr="label" store="sampleNameStore" name="sample_name" class="selectionNav tableData"></select>
```

It works extremely well but it doesn't populate the ComboBox until the ComboBox is actually selected due to dojo's behavior of not loading the store into memory until the ComboBox is accessed. I'd love to have the ComboBoxes to populate after the page has loaded.

The ability to use a simple one-liner to tie the ComboBox to a data source is so awesome and simple. Does anyone know a way to force the store into memory on load?

Janie

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch items with a `dijit.byId('sampleNameStore').fetch()` :) store.fetch with an empty query if you want all data to be loaded.
If you do that before displaying the comboBox, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have often used a cloned memorystore for comboboxes to allow more control over key labels, example here maps *title* to *name*

With

```
var store = ?;
var combobox = ?; 
var data=[];
function clone(items) {
   items.forEach(function(item) { 
       data.push( {name: store.getValue(item, "title"), id: store.getValue(item, 'id')} );
   });
   combobox.set("store", new memorystore({
     data:data
   }));
}
```

Either

```
store.on("load", function() { clone(store._arrayOfAllItems) });
```

Or

```
 store.fetch({ onComplete: function(items) {clone(items);} });
```

Comment: How's it hangin'? Have problems or you got em sorted?